# velocity.js sequences transitions

Tags: javascript, sequences, velocity.js

I want to use the velocity.js sequences, with transition.slideUpDown.

If I use it in this way, it works.
$($element).velocity("transition.slideUpDown", 500);

But if I want to use it with sequences I can not get it to work.

```
elements: $Element,
  properties: {
    translateX: -100 // this works
    //does not work
    transition: {
      slideUpDown: 500
    }
  },
  options: {
    duration: 1000
    loop: 5
  }
```

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing API's here. The `"transition.slide*"` is a UI Pack effect, where as the `properties` object needs contain CSS properties.

You could do the [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/a7ktvscy/).

Inside the fiddle above there's a sequence with the translation call and then the transition effect call.

Note, however, that the `loop` option will not work there.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
That helped me, to get it worked, as I wished.